# CGEventCreateScrollWheelEvent can't work as Zoom in/out as Control key is press

Tags: macos, operating-system, key, modifier

I can use Event Tap/CGEventCreateScrollWheelEvent to send scroll event to HID Tap.

But as I keep sending the scroll events and also pressing the control key at the same time,

the expected Zoom in/out does not come.

Is the HID Event tap too high level ? Will IOHIDPostEvent be a better API to send mouse
event as modifier key is taken into consideration?

Thank you.